# Using Time columns with NHibernate, Fluent NHibernate and SQL Server 2008

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table with a time column in my SQL Server 2008 database.

The property of the object I'm trying to map to is a TimeSpan.

How can i tell FluentNHibernate to use the TimeAsTimeSpan NHibernate type, so that I don't have cast problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And if you're using the conventions, then this does the job for me:

```
public class PropertyConvention : IPropertyConvention 
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Property.PropertyType == typeof(TimeSpan))
            instance.CustomType( "TimeAsTimeSpan" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is working for me:

```
Map(x => x.TimeFrom)
    .CustomType("TimeAsTimeSpan");
```

Comment: That works, but how do you deal with NULL values in the database? TimeSpan.Zero is equal to new TimeSpan(0,0,0) so that won't work, and gets persisted as "00:00:00" by NHibernate's TimeAsTimeSpanType. Poking through the source-code, it does not appear to handle NULL-values at all? Whether I put NULL or "00:00:00" in a column, this comes back from NHibernate as TimeSpan.Zero either way. What gives?

Comment: @mindplay.dk `TimeSpan` can't represent `null`. `TimeSpan?` can.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to map it using [CustomType](http://www.mail-archive.com/fluent-nhibernate@googlegroups.com/msg04352.html).

Comment: What do I put in CustomType? TimeAsTimeSpan or DBType.Time?

With TimeAsTimeSpan I get an exception as the type doesn't have a constructor with no parameters

Comment: The first line of the linked article is "CustomType("TimeAsTimeSpan") should work fine".